# Build model 'java.lang.Void' for root project?

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I upgrade a simple android project from gradle 4.10.x to gradle-kotlin-dsl (with gradle 5.3.1).
It works fine as below:

```
completed successfully  700 ms
Run build   485 ms
Load build  3 ms
Configure build 380 ms
Calculate task graph    25 ms
Run tasks   71 ms
Build model 'java.lang.Void' for root project 'MyProject'
```

But the last lin seems missing something.
Does anyone known why?

I just rename `settings.gradle` to `settgings.gradle.kts`, and change `include ':app'` to `include(":app")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrade to Android Studio 3.4, gradle 5.4, android gradle plugin 3.4.0, the last line disappeared.